# Wifi not working properly 11.10 ubuntu

Tags: wireless

When I boot up my Lenevo V570 to ubuntu 11.10 then it shows me 'Wireless hardware switch off' however when i use windows and then reboot ubuntu then it works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your `rfkill list` say?

Try to type into your terminal 'rfkill unblock wifi' or 'rfkill unblock wlan'. You might need to execute this as root ('sudo').

Good luck.